# Database Management source code for study

Tags: database

I wants to have some knowledge about how database management software is implemented. Is there any project whose source code is available.
Moreover I am not an expert in database related things, just having some knowledge of using MySQL database. So it will nice to get that code which I can understand.

Any advice regarding this will be helpful

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the PostgreSQL source code is very well suited for learning (I have heard - but cannot confirm - that it's used at some universities for teaching DBMS development).

The source code can be downloaded here: http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v9.1.3/

If you are more familiar with Java, you might want to look into one of the open source Java DBMS engines:

- HyberSQL: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/
- H2: http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/checkout
- Apache Derby: http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html

Comment: Thanks for the for information you have given.
I think I should continue with postgresql as it is in C++ and I am more comfortable in it comparing with JAVA and if I hope I'll  be able to understand something out of it.

Thanks a alot!

Answer (score 1):

For Firebird you can check [how to build code here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/building-the-code/)

If you need help you can ask [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/development-mailing-lists/)

and http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=7127

Comment: Not mention before but it is also C++